# dot to comma conversion with language change

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my application providing 3 different languages(**English,Spanish,French**).
Whenever I am change language from **English** to **Spanish/English** to **French** then it will convert decimal numbers from dot to comma and its create an issue for me. so how can I prevent this issue or solve this issue ?

My language conversion code seems like below :

```
function set_lang($lang=FALSE){

        $current_locale=$this->CI->session->userdata('user_language');
        if(empty($current_locale)){
             $current_locale= 'en_US';
        }
    putenv("LANG=$current_locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $current_locale.".UTF-8");
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,$current_locale);
    setlocale(LC_TIME, $current_locale);
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,$current_locale);
    $domain='messages';
    $uri_segment='';
     $uri_segment = $this->CI->uri->segments;
    if(isset($uri_segment[1])){ 
        $filename = getcwd().'/application/modules/user/language/'.$lang.'/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo';
                bindtextdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN,getcwd().'/application/modules/'.$uri_segment[1].'/language/');
    }
    bind_textdomain_codeset(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8');
    textdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN);
         return true;
    }
```

Any ideas ? Any suggestions ?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Why do you want not to change it?

Comment: Why is it an issue?

Comment: because its not required like my amount 0.2 then need to show like 0,2

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's number format for this, use it like this: number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have already resolve this issue with str_replace